# Rails: validates_numericality_of on attr_accessor not working as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using rails 3.1. I have a model Product something like this:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :output_unit
  ...
  validates_numericality_of :output_unit, greater_than_or_equal_to => 0, :on => update
  ...
end
```

When I try to update a product and I introduce a number on this field, form message display "output unit is not a number".

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What is the data type of "output_unit" in your database? (e.g., as shown in `db/schema.rb`)

Comment: This attribute is not stored in the database is a virtual attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You can write the method `output_unit_before_type_cast` and return `self.output_unit`, try this :

```
 attr_accessor :output_unit

 validates_numericality_of :output_unit, :only_integer => true, greater_than_or_equal_to => 0, :on => update

 def output_unit_before_type_cast
    self.output_unit
 end
```

Or

```
 attr_accessor :output_unit
 validates :output_unit, :numericality => { :only_integer => true, :greater_than_or_equal_to => 0, :on => update }

 def output_unit_before_type_cast
    self.output_unit
 end
```

Comment: I just try but the result is the same when I introduce a number same message "is not a number".

Comment: I have update my answer, if all not works, try remove `self.`